# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode9.1

When i am run project in Xcode then showing some  error that means my add pod file is unknown error

and

error screen short

[Screen Short Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfcmo.png)

and showing error text is

"/Users/Appsfactor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/You_Task-hfbipjtwskuqvfgdnnjienomkrbm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/You Task/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//You Task.app/Frameworks/ALCameraViewController.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1"

Comment: Did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your Keychain certificates pertaining your current project and rebuild using new certificates from developer.apple.com and try. Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

1. Clear Derived Data
2. Empty your Trash
3. Clean your Xcode Project and Run again.

Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

1. Just update your Pods or re - install the same.
2. Clear Derived Data

It'll work

Answer (score -1):

1. Clear Derived Data
2. restart system
3. after open **Xcode** and run, it will work